# Prove $\forall K > 0: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{K} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Alright, so I've already proven that both $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{n} = 1$ and $\forall K\geq 1:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{K}=1$.

I got the feeling, that I can prove $\forall  K \in \mathbb{R}> 0: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{K} = 1$ with a simple limit comparison test but I can't figure out how exactly.

Comment: I think you meant (or should have meant) to write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt [n] K=1\,$$ in your post's second line

Comment: @DonAntonio you're right, fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $0<K<1$, $K=1/x$ for some $x>1$.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can proove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}=1$ by applying the Bernoulli inequality to $\sqrt{n}=(1+a_n)^{n/2}$ where $a_n=\sqrt{n}-1$.

Answer (score 0):

From the [root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) it follows that for a positive sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ while if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}>1$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=+\infty$.
Since for the sequence $a_n=K$, we have $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_n=K>0$ it follows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{K}=1$.