# How can one prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a^{1/n}=1$ for every $a>0$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ if $a >0$. 
In my textbook, we are given a suggestion to let $a^{\frac{1}{n}} = (1+h_n)$ and then show that the $h_n$ term goes to zero using a Theorem that states the following conditions:

$\lim_{n \to \infty} = \infty,$ if $a >1, 1,$ if $a = 1,$ and 0, if $\vert a \vert < 1$.
I apologize for not formatting the above cases appropriately; I could not figure out how to use a giant left brace to group them altogether.

If I rewrite it as $a^{n^{-1}}$, then I thought that this might help, but I don't think the Binomial Theorem would then apply since the exponent is negative. Furthermore, the problem is only concerned with the positive, real $n$-th roots. I am quite stuck on this problem and any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I am using the textbook *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck.

Comment: The binomial theorem does apply to negative exponents. For example, $(1+X)^{-1} = 1 + (-1)X + (-1)(-2)/2 X^2 + (-1)(-2)(-3)/3! X^3 + ... = 1 - X + X^2 - X^3 + ...$

Comment: Oh, yes you are absolutely correct. I made a mistake there. Thank you for pointing that one out.

Comment: The error has been corrected in the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $\forall K > 0: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt[n]{K} = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229672/prove-forall-k-0-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnk-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{a} =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679304/show-that-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtna-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:
I first saw this in "What is Mathematics?"
by Courant and Robbins.

You need two cases:
$0 < a < 1$
and $a > 1$.
These both use the motto
"Always expand around zero."

These cases both use
Bernoulli's inequality
(if $x \ge 0$ and $n \ge 1$
then $(1+x)^n \ge 1+xn$).
These also implicitly
use the Archimedean axiom
for the real numbers
(for any positive reals
$x$ and $y$
there is an integer $m$
such that
$mx > y$).

If $a > 1$,
let $a^{1/n} = 1+b$
where $b > 0$.
Then
$a 
=(1+b)^n
\ge 1+bn
$
so
$b 
\le \frac{a-1}{n}
$.
We can make $b < \epsilon$
for any $\epsilon$
by choosing 
$n
> \frac{a-1}{\epsilon}
$.

If $0 < a < 1$,
let $a^{1/n} = \frac1{1+b}$
where $b > 0$.
Then
$a = \frac1{(1+b)^n}$.
As before,
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+bn
$,
so

$\begin{align}
&a 
\le
\frac1{1+bn}\\
&\text{or}\\
&\frac1{a}
\ge 1+bn\\
&\text{or}\\
&b 
\le \frac{1/a-1}{n}\\
&\text{or}\\
&1+b 
\le 1+\frac{1/a-1}{n}
= \frac{n+1/a-1}{n}\\
&\text{or}\\
&\frac1{1+b} 
\ge \frac{n}{n+1/a-1}
= 1-\frac{1/a-1}{n+1/a-1}\\
\end{align}
$

We can make
$\frac1{1+b} 
> 1-\epsilon
$
by making
$n+1/a-1
>\frac{1/a-1}{\epsilon}
$
or
$n
>(\frac1{a}-1)(\frac1{\epsilon}-1)
$
for any
$\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Ok, it took me a while to understand this proof. I am only a little confused on the part where you add 1 to both sides of the inequality $b \leq \frac{1/a-1}{n}$. Is this used to produce a very small $\epsilon$ when the reciprocal law is applied?

Comment: That's because we need to get $\frac1{1+b}$, and to get that we need $1+b$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Then what happens in the final step when $\frac{1}{1+b} \geq \frac{n}{n+1/a-1}$? In other words, how does that become $\frac{n}{n+1/a-1} = 1 - \frac{1/a-1}{n+1/a-1}$? Thank you, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

**Case 1:** Suppose that $a\gt 1$. Let $a=1+\delta$, where $\delta$ is positive.

We claim that if $n \ge 1$ then 
$$1\le a^{1/n}\lt 1+\frac{\delta}{n}.\tag{1}$$
The fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a^{1/n}=1$ is an immediate consequence of Inequality (1).

To prove (1), suppose to the contrary that $a^{1/n}\gt 1+\frac{\delta}{n}$.  Then 
$$a=(a^{1/n})^n\gt \left(1+\frac{\delta}{n}\right)^n.\tag{2}$$
But by the **Bernoulli Inequality**,
$$\left(1+\frac{\delta}{n}\right)^n \ge 1+n\frac{\delta}{n}=1+\delta.\tag{3}$$
From (2) and (3) we conclude that $a\gt 1+\delta$, contradicting the fact that $a=1+\delta$.

**Case 2:** Suppose that $0\lt a\lt 1$. Let $b=\frac{1}{a}$. Then $b\gt 1$. By Case 1, $b^{1/n}$ has limit $1$, and therefore so does $a^{1/n}$.

**Remarks:** $1.$ The Bernoulli Inequality states that if $t\gt -1$, then $(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt$. We only need it for $t\gt 0$. In that case, it is an immediate consequence of the Binomial Theorem. There is also a quite  simple induction proof.

$2.$ We gave a quite  formal proof. But it comes down to the fact that a number $\gt 1$ raised to a large enough power is very large, and in particular greater than $a$.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with Bernoulli's Inequality; there is a small section at the end of this chapter in my textbook about it. This post helps to better understand how it can be used. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. The Bernoulli Inequality can be useful.

Comment: This proves it for $a > 1$. The OP also asked for $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: I did not notice. Will try to deal with that tomorrow. It is the same, instead of calling $a$ by the name $1+\delta$, one calls it $\frac{1}{1+\delta}$.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154163/limit-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-sqrtnn/154188#154188) and then use the squeeze theorem with:

$$(1)\;\;a>1\implies 1\le\sqrt[n] a\le\sqrt[n]n\;\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;n\ge a\\(2)\;\;a<1\implies\;\text{use arithmetic of limits with}\;\;b:=\frac1a>1\ldots$$

Comment: Thank you very much for showing me that link. It was very helpful.