# Spivak, Ch. 22, Problem 18: $a_n>0$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l$, prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=l$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The following is a problem from Chapter 22 "Infinite Sequences" of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 18. Suppose that $a_n>0$ for each $n$ and that $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=l\tag{1}$$ Prove that
>
> $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n}=l\tag{2}$$

My solution differed from the solution manual, so I wanted to check its correctness.

Here is my solution attempt

$$a_n(l-\epsilon)<a_{n+1}<a_n(l+\epsilon)$$

$$a_{n+1}(l-\epsilon)<a_{n+2}<a_{n+1}(l+\epsilon)$$

$$a_n(l-\epsilon)^2<a_{n+2}<a_n(l+\epsilon)^2$$

Thus

$$a_n(l-\epsilon)^m<a_{n+m}<a_n(l+\epsilon)^m$$

$$\sqrt[n+m]{a_n(l-\epsilon)^m}<\sqrt[n+m]{a_{n+m}}<\sqrt[n+m]{a_n(l+\epsilon)^{m}}$$

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{a_n}\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{(l-\epsilon)^m}<\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{a_{n+m}}<\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{a_n}\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{(l+\epsilon)^m}\tag{1}$$

Since $a_n>0$, then $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{a_n}=1$.

$l>0$ since $a_n>0$. Note that $l\neq 0$ since then $(1)$ would be false.

Thus

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{(l-\epsilon)^m}=l-\epsilon$$

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{(l+\epsilon)^m}=l+\epsilon$$

and

$$l-\epsilon<\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sqrt[n+m]{a_{n+m}}<1+\epsilon$$

for every $\epsilon>0$. Thus

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sqrt[n+m]{a_{n+m}}=l$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I just noticed that I will need to reformulate what I wrote. I need to use an argument that uses terms in the sequence above some value $N$. I can't use things like $a_1$. So hold off please until I make this change.

Comment: Don't take limits on both sides of an inequality, unless you have proved the exsitence of the limits. I mean, $A_n\leq B_n$ doesn't imply $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}B_n$, unless they both exist. Here, you don't know the existence of $\lim \sqrt[n]{a_n}$ in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $a_{n+1}/a_n\to\ell$ show $a_n^{1/n}\to\ell$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575310/if-a-n1-a-n-to-ell-show-a-n1-n-to-ell) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Ba_%7Bn%2B1%7D%7D%7Ba_n%7D%3Dl%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%5Cinfty%7D%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Ba_n%7D%3Dl%24&p=2). Note the OP's attempt there appears to be very similar to yours, with that question's [accepted answer](/a/2578020) completing the argument.

Comment: @evianpring FYI, the search also turned up several posts that used this result, such as in this [answer](/a/1629630) which defined & proved it as a lemma, as well as just stating it in this other question's [answer](/a/1901943), and in the AoPS thread's [Infinite limit - Message #4](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1709410p11019173).

Comment: @Feng I have reformulated by proof. I think the step you write about is now $(1)$. Take, for example, $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sqrt[n+m]{a_n(l-\epsilon)^m}=\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} \sqrt[n+m]{a_n}\lim\limits{m\to\infty} \sqrt[n+m]{(l-\epsilon)^m}$. Proving that these individual limits exist can be done relatively easily. Then it is fine, right?

Comment: I was talking about $(1)$. But my point is the middle term of $(1)$: $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[n+m]{a_{n+m}}$. We don't know the existence of this limit in advance.

Comment: I know this doesn't directly adress your question, but a stronger result is in   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69386/inequality-involving-limsup-and-liminf-liminfa-n1-a-n-le-liminf

Comment: Note also that taking log your exercise is equivalent to Cesàro's theorem.