# Understanding an MSE proof of $\lim_{n \to \infty} p^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ ($p >0$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-explanation

> Let $p$ be a positive real number. How can one prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} p^{\frac{1}{n}} = 1$?

I searched around the site and read [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/703124/9464) (using the intermediate value theorem) under the old (2014) post:

[$\lim_{n \to \infty}x^{1/n}=1$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/703117)

But I don't understand it:

- I don't think that it's complete because the argument from $p=(1+q_n)^n \geq 1+nq_n \geq nq_n > 0$ only works for $p \geq 1$.
- Why can we just say **if** $p^{\frac1n} = 1+q_n$? What if not?

Below is the orginal proof where I have adapted to my notation:

---

> $f(p)=p^n$ is continuous and strictly increasing in $[0,1+p_0]$, and 
>   $$ f(0)=0<p_0<f(1+p_0)=(1+p_0)^n $$ and hence there exists a unique
>   $q_0\in (0,1+q_0)$, such that  $$ f(q_0)=q_0^n=p_0. $$
>
> Now, if $p^{1/n}=1+q_n$, then  $$ p=(1+q_n)^n\ge 1+n q_n\ge n q_n>0,
> > $$ and thus $$ 0<q_n\le\frac{p}{n}\to 0, $$ and hence $$
> p^{1/n}=1+q_n\to 1. $$

Comment: Where did you see the proof? Can you cite the reference?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=p^x$ instead of $p^n$?

Comment: @Jack I got it from here and adapted it with $p$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703117/lim-n-to-inftyx1-n-1-for-every-x-in-mathbbr-and-x0

Comment: Thanks for that. There are several answers for that post. Which one do you refer to? [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/703124/9464) one?

Comment: @Jack Yes, that's the one.

Comment: @robjohn left a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703117/lim-n-to-inftyx1-n-1-for-every-x-in-mathbbr-and-x0/703124#comment1473332_703124) there that one needs to handle the case when $0<x<1$. Is your question about that?

Comment: @Jack Yes. I didn't want to comment there because the thread is 5 years old and no one would reply to that one

Comment: OK. I have edited your post accordingly.

Comment: @Jack Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: I personally don't like that proof. Using the binomial theorem is much simpler; it does not require mentioning any continuous functions.

Comment: And you are right, the proof there is poorly written.

Comment: One way to make sense of this is to first do the case where $p \geq 1$. In this case, $f(1)=1\leq p \leq (1+p)^n$ (you can even use $p\leq p^n$ for the upper bound, instead) and, via the IVT, conclude the existence of an $n$th root of $p$ between $1$ and $1+p$. In particular, this root is $\geq 1$, so it can be expressed as $1+q_n$ for _some_ nonnegative $q_n$. Then you can conclude the argument as presented in the question. For the case where $0<p<1$, note that since $\frac{1}{p}>1$, the limit of $\frac{1}{p}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n$ goes to infinity will be $1$. Conclude from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments, you mentioned that your question was regarding the fact that the proof cited only works for $p\ge1$. If $p\lt 1$, then $\frac1p\gt1$ and the proof there shows that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1p\right)^{1/n}=1
$$
Since $\frac1x$ is continuous at $x=1$, we can then say that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}p^{1/n}=\frac11=1
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the continuity of the exponential function :
$\lim_{n\to\infty} p^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \exp(\frac{1}{n}\ln p)= \exp(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln p) = \exp(0)=1$.